# Zabbix 5.4 - Override Template Macro

Tags: zabbix

I have a discovery rule that is used to create hard disks as items for Windows Hosts.
The item prototype looks like this:`vfs.fs.size[{#DISKNUMLET},free]`

The Trigger Prototype looks like this:

```
last(/t_task_LogicalHarddrive_Windows/vfs.fs.size[{#DISKNUMLET},pfree])<={$MIN_PROCENT_FREE_SPACE:"{#DISKNUMLET}"}
```

The template has the macro for free space:`{$MIN_PROCENT_FREE_SPACE} = 15`

Since the server has 3 disks, 3 triggers are created.

```
last(/servername/vfs.fs.size[C:,pfree])<={$MIN_PROCENT_FREE_SPACE: "C:"}
last(/servername/vfs.fs.size[D:,pfree])<={$MIN_PROCENT_FREE_SPACE: "D:"}
last(/servername/vfs.fs.size[E:,pfree])<={$MIN_PROCENT_FREE_SPACE: "E:"}
```

I would like to know how to overwrite the inherited macro for drive E with a different value.
If I remember correctly, I have to create an appropriate macro directly on the host... but I have no idea how this has to look exactly?

Does anyone have any idea?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost achieved what you want.

Just create `{$MIN_PROCENT_FREE_SPACE: "E:"} = whatever value you want` macro directly in host macros.

Host macros overwrite inherited macros.

Comment: Thank you very much for this.
That was easy.